# VBA Excel: Draw line between cells based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm racking my brain with task. I need to draw line from cell to cell based on value (if not 0). In each row coul'd be only 1 value - rest of them is 0.
Line started and ended in center of cell.

Do anyone know how to code it?

[PrintScreen - How should the result look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehmSI.png)

I'm completly lost

Answer (score 0):

This code creates `msoConnectorStraight` shapes on the parameter `RangeToConnect` based on your description and with the connectors' end centered on the cells.
**Note**: 1 line is in charge of skipping empty rows; you can comment it if empty rows should be ignored.

```
Sub ConnectValues(RangeToConnect As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = RangeToConnect.Parent
    
    'Clear the existing shapes on the range
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ws.Shapes
        If s.Type = msoConnectorStraight And _
            Not Application.Intersect(RangeToConnect, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing And _
            Not Application.Intersect(RangeToConnect, s.BottomRightCell) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    Next s
    
    'Add the connectors to the range
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, r As Range, c As Range
    For Each r In RangeToConnect.Rows
        Set cell2 = cell1
        Set cell1 = Nothing 'Breaks the line on empty rows, to be commented if they should be ignored.
        For Each c In r.Cells
            If VBA.Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                Set cell1 = c
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If Not cell1 Is Nothing And Not cell2 Is Nothing Then
            ws.Shapes.AddConnector _
                msoConnectorStraight, _
                cell1.Left + cell1.Width / 2, cell1.Top + cell1.Height / 2, _
                cell2.Left + cell2.Width / 2, cell2.Top + cell2.Height / 2
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```